# How do I enable invocation of a program in bash without an explicit path?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, shell

For example, I can run `ln`, `nano`, and programs I installed over `apt` like `sl` or `worms` without having to give the full path. However, when I build a program/package/software manually/using `make`/using something else, I have to invoke it using the full path, in my case `~/ghc/bin/ghc`. How do you tell `bash`, or for that matter, `sh`, which names exist?

I know how to do this on Windows, but as far as I know, there's no equivalent of `%PATH%` in Linux/Unix/Ubuntu (in my case).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is - the variable is called `$PATH`.

You may make a program globally accessible by copying it to any path that's listed under `$PATH`, such as `/usr/bin` or `/usr/local/bin` or `/bin`.

The recommended place to add your own custom binaries is `/usr/local/bin` though.

You may also add new directories to the `$PATH` by overwriting the variable in your shell start script (in `~/.bashrc`, or `~/.bash_profile`):

```
export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/myfolder/bin"
```

You can find out more about the recommended meanings for UNIX filesystem paths [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard).

Comment: To be strict: the variable is called `PATH` both in Windows and in Unix/Linux. You refer to a variable named `foo` with `%foo%` and `$foo` respectively, hence `%PATH%` and `$PATH`; but it's the syntax to *retrieve* the value that is different, not the name itself. Commands that take name (not value) need no `%`/`$`, e.g. `set PATH=…`.

Comment: Thanks! Why do you use ":" after "$PATH"?

Comment: @schuelermine `:` is the separator between multiple paths in the variable, just like `;` in Windows.